# Why do I keep getting error with this LEFT JOIN method?

Tags: sql, left-join

```
             string query = "SELECT title FROM gameDetails g ";
                    query += "LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.ratingID= g.ratingID ";
                    query += "WHERE r.rUser=@usr";
```

I have a table called gameDetails that has 3 column - gameID, title and ratingID

and another table called rating that has 2 column - ratingID, rUser

What seems to be the problem here?  I keep receiving this error:  `Invalid column name 'ratingID'.`

Comment: there is no space between `g.ratingID` and `WHERE` clause?

Comment: still receive the same thing

Comment: You're right, but you would think it would say `Invalid column name 'ratingIDWHERE'`

Comment: rather than that, I don't know. check for triggers if you have any.

Comment: Can you run the queries individually successfully? Is it at all possible that one of the tables' columns has a typo?

Comment: Yes I can and there isn't any typo.  I copy and paste the column name in the sql server itself.

Comment: Is it when running the query, or when pulling the results of the query? You're only selecting the title and not ratingID. If you go to pull it from the result set it won't be there.

Comment: You mean something like `string query = "SELECT title, g.ratingID FROM gameDetails g ";`?  Tried that, it won't work

Comment: @user3195396 - yes, that's what I was suggesting. So the error is when running the query itself and not when pulling data from the result set?  If so, I'm at a loss. If the tables are as you describe then it looks pretty straightforward and should be working.

Comment: Try typing: "SELECT gameID, title, ratingID FROM gameDetails".  If that doesn't work, remove one column and try again.  Keep swapping columns and see if any work and don't work.  Then you'll know which ones don't work.  Rename any that don't work and see if they work with the renames.  This is really a Sherlock Holmes issue; work to cancel out all possible reasons, and whatever is left is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  The only way to solve this mysterious problem is to re-create the whole table and its relationships.